# How to expose a jbpm workflow as web service

Tags: jbpm

I am using jbpm 3.2.Also i am using jbpm console & mysql as db on Tomcat 6.

I have created a sample workflow.Now i want to create a web service out of it & expose it to some third party application.

Does anyone know how i can do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jBPM is no more than a hostable api. You can deploy it along with any other dependencies in most java based web service containers.

In our case we created an Axis2 based web service where certain generic method calls call into the hosted jBPM workflows we developed.

This is a good deployment pattern as multiple applications can participate in the same workflow or share the same workflow infrastructure.